# Boost.Thread throws bad_alloc exception in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, boost-thread

Upon including `<boost/thread.hpp>` I get this exception:

```
First-chance exception at 0x7c812afb in CSF.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: 
boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::bad_alloc_> at memory location 0x0012fc3c..
First-chance exception at 0x7c812afb in CSF.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000..
```

I can't catch it, breaking at the memory location brings me to kernel32.dll and at this point I cannot say what's going on but it appears that the exception is thrown after the program ends and VS is capable of catching it.

The testcase:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

Compiler command line:
`/I"I:\SophisPal\boost-1_43_0-vc10-32\include\boost-1_43" /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /O2 /Oi /Oy- /GL /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm- /EHsc /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Release\Client.pch" /Fa"Release\" /Fo"Release\" /Fd"Release\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue`

Linker command line:
`/OUT:"C:\Documents and Settings\user\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\CSF\Release\Client.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO "I:\SophisPal\boost-1_43_0-vc10-32\lib\libboost_system-vc100-mt-1_43.lib" "I:\SophisPal\boost-1_43_0-vc10-32\lib\libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-1_43.lib" "I:\SophisPal\boost-1_43_0-vc10-32\lib\libboost_regex-vc100-mt-1_43.lib" "I:\SophisPal\boost-1_43_0-vc10-32\lib\libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_43.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Release\Client.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Documents and Settings\user\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\CSF\Release\Client.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /PGD:"C:\Documents and Settings\user\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\CSF\Release\Client.pgd" /LTCG /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE`

Comment: Post code, not binaries. No one in their right mind would run your binary blindly.

Comment: Agreed.  Binaries are for viruses, code is for solutions.

Comment: There is no code... It's just an empty main. I'll remove it if you wish.

Comment: That's why you post the code, not the main, so that other people can see it.

Make sure that you have the latest version.

Comment: **There is no code**. I Just include boost/thread.hpp and I have an empty main that returns 0. that's it

Comment: @the_drow: Do you have CLR support enabled? (`/clr` flag is set when compiling). .NET and Boost Threads do not play nicely together.  I built and ran your project without `/clr` and had no issues (VC++2010 and Boost 1.43.0).  You should definitely post your compiler and linker command lines.

Comment: @James McNellis: Added and the clr flag is not there.

Comment: @the_drow:  Why are you manually linking in the Boost libraries?  Under Visual C++, inclusion of the Boost headers will automatically cause the necessary libraries to be linked as long as you have the Boost libs folder in the linker additional libraries path.

Comment: @James McNellis: And how would I do that? Is it related? Notice I am offering a bounty on the question :)

Comment: boost::thread has some problems with rvalue references and wont even compile with gcc + std=c++0x. Could this be related?

Comment: It might be... All I'm seeing here is something that doesn't get along well with VS 2010 memory allocators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was by design in boost 1.43 but has been since fixed. See [this thread](http://old.nabble.com/Boost-1.43---Exception-before-main()-is-called-tt28536505.html#a28536505) for the details.

Comment: Link is now broken and the answer does not include details which indicate what the link contained. What was the thread about?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a mismatch between the Boost static libraries and the header files.  How did you install boost?  Did you run the bootstrap.bat on the machine to build it?  Did you modify the boost header files after compilation?  Do you have a library directory reference in the VS 2008 global settings to a directory containing a different version of the boost libraries?

Put another way, have you tried a clean install of boost with the libraries compiled with bootstrap.bat and have you deleted all other boost implementations on your machine?  Until you've done that, you're working on a less-than-solid foundation.

If you still have trouble after that, have you tried going to Debug->Exceptions and turning on breaking on first-chance C++ and Win32 exceptions so that you can see the call stack in the debugger?  If that doesn't work, have you tried using the Win32 API `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter()`, passing in a callback that uses the `MiniDumpWriteDump()` API of `DBGHELP.DLL` to write out a mini-dump (*.dmp) of the process to a file that you can then post-mortem debug using the VS 2010 debugger?

Comment: I don't know those functions. Got any links to explain how this is done.
I got the libraries from a friend who compiled them on an exact machine but tried recompiling. It doesn't help

Comment: MiniDumpWriteDump: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680360(VS.85).aspx, http://www.debuginfo.com/examples/effmdmpexamples.html
SetUnhandledExceptionFilter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634(VS.85).aspx, http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/debugfilters.html

Comment: I wonder if the 'accepted' answer actually worked for the poster. I'm currently experiencing the same problem and I would appreciate some help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428177/boost-crash-when-linking-visual-studio-2008-express-mtd-setting

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue with version 4.6.1 of g++ - boost version 1.47.0

The error is very vague, does not point to any particular section of code. After a lot of efforts it was traced to addition of `pragma pack(1)` directive, but not closed before declaring STL templates and or boost library data member templates.

The fix was to remove all `pragma pack(x)` and use GNU style packing `"__attribute__((packed))"` for the required structures

Boost should better in pointing error / warnings while linking with its libraries.

Comment: @durron597 Actually why not? If he can add more info about the problem it might help someone else later on. If you think the answer is inaccurate or incorrect downvote it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying to create a new, empty, Win32 Console Application (I usually check the "Empty Project" checkbox as well so as not to get precompiled headers and such for small projects).

Add a **.cpp** file to the project and give it your contents.

In the project properties, under **C/C++ -> General**, in the **Additional Include Directories** box, add the path to your top-level Boost folder (the one that contains the folder named **boost** that has all the header files).  In my case, it's **z:\dev\boost_1_43_0**; based on your post, yours is probably **I:\SophisPal\boost-1_43_0-vc10-32\include\boost-1_43**.

Also in the project properties, under **Linker -> General**, in the **Additional Library Directories** box, add the path to the folder containing the compiled Boost libraries.  On my PC, this is **z:\dev\boost_1_43_0\lib**; based on your post, yours is probably **I:\SophisPal\boost-1_43_0-vc10-32\lib**.

You don't need to explicitly tell the linker which libraries you want to link against; the Boost headers use one of the Visual C++ `#pragma` directives to tell the linker which libraries need to be used.

With just that, you should be able to build and run both Debug and Release configurations.  I went through exactly these steps on and had no issues.

If that works, I'd start modifying the project, one option at a time, until it matches your current project's configuration.  Eventually something will make it stop working, then you'll know what the problem is.

If that *doesn't* work, I'd look at downloading the Boost source and building it again.

Comment: Done that, and even tried to link to an older version of boost. Same exception.

Comment: @the_drow:  At that point, I'd consider trying on another machine or in a clean VM with the same source or uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio 2010.  I'm fresh out of other ideas, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts:

How do you know that the crash is occuring *after* main()?

What happens if you run from a debugger and configure VS to catch every exception (not just unhandled)?

Can you post a stack trace of the crash?

Comment: I know because I see it happens AFTER my return 0. All I see is is some debug related memory code. How do I post the stack trace?

Comment: You tell VS to break on SEH exceptions, and when the debugger breaks upon the crash you can see the stack trace. Alternatively you can trigger a crash dump and then analyze the dump in WinDbg or VS. Dr. Watson is probably the default post-mortem debugger, and it does just that (you just have to grab the dump file before it deletes it).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a memory profiler like [VLD](http://sites.google.com/site/dmoulding/vld) (Windows) or Valgrind (Linux) to check if it can point to the bad allocation, maybe you have a version of the Boost library that contains an incompatibility bug with your current compiler and you might have to apply a fix.

Answer (score 1):

You either have a bad build or messed up project settings since you've tried creating a new basic project and simply including the header I'd suggest recompiling boost.  You can download the latest version 1.45 from sourceforge which is linked from boost.org.  Grab the latest bjam while you're there.  You can run the following commands from your visual studio command prompt to build boost in 64bit and 32bit:

```
bjam --build-type=complete --toolset=msvc-10.0 --stagedir=lib64 address-model=64 stage > x64-buildboost.log
RD bin.v2 /S /Q
bjam --build-type=complete --toolset=msvc-10.0 --stagedir=lib32 stage > x86-buildboost.log
RD bin.v2 /S /Q
```

On a side note if the CSF reference refers to Intel's Communications Services Framework open source telephony project I worked on that before and upgrading boost with that project back in the day broke more things than it fixed ... fair warning.