# Boost crash when linking Visual Studio 2008 Express '/Mtd' setting

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

#### TLDR

Linking my fresh boost build with Visual Studio (/Mtd) causes boost to throw a 'bad_alloc' exception before entering the main function.

#### Details

I built the boost library using the instructions from the [Getting Started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) instructions. After setting up the prerequisites I used the following build command:

```
bjam -j8 --build-dir="C:\Development\Boost\boost-build" --build-type=complete msvc stage
```

Above command seems to build all combinations of debug/release and shared/static builds.

Then I created a empty Visual Studio project and added the following code in the main file:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I also changed the Code Generation settings to Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd).

At this point I did not yet configure any library paths in my project. So the build ended with the following linker error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc90-mt-sgd-1_43.lib'
```

Ok, I find this file in my boost build and copy it to '$(SolutionDir)3rdParty\Boost_1_43_0\libs' which I added to the *Additional Library Directories*. Next error follows:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc90-mt-sgd-1_43.lib'
```

Ok, I also find this file in my boost build directory and copy it to my library path.

After this the project builds succesfully, but a 'bad_alloc" exception is thrown in boost code, before entering the main function.

It seems that there is a library incompatibility here. Does anyone know what exactly is going wrong, and how to fix it?

#### Update

Since [James McNellis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151292/james-mcnellis) mentioned that this may be something specific to the thread library I tried out 'program_options' and this one doesn't cause any problems (main body is still empty though).

A simple sample application using the boost 'signal' library works fine also. So it's really the thread library that's causing some problem.

#### Version

I'm currently using Boost v1.43.0, I'll see if I can reproduce the problem with v1.42.

#### BCP

One detail I'd like to mention is that I am using a stripped down version of Boost. I created a subset using the following [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) utility:

```
mkdir ./output
bcp bind function lexical_cast noncopyable optional program_options smart_ptr signals signals2 thread ./output
```

This probably isn't causing the 'bad_alloc' though...

#### Boost 1.42

I just installed Boost 1.42 using the [BoostPro Installe](http://www.boostpro.com/download/)r. A quick test revealed that it works fine like this. Strange...

Comment: Did you compile the C++ project with CLR support?  (There is a fundamental incompatibility between Boost.Thread, which uses the Win32 TLS, and the .NET runtime.  I don't know what the details are, but basically you usually cannot mix the two inside a single binary).

Comment: @James McNellis, no, I just used the General -> Empty Project option. Unless CLR is implicitly enabled. "Disable Language Extensions" is set to "No" (the default), I don't know if that matters?

Comment: @Stacked:  Check "Common Language Runtime Support" on the "Configuration Properties > General" property page and make sure it is set to "No Common Language Runtime Support."

Comment: @James: I checked and it was set to "No Common Language Runtime support". So that's ok.

Comment: @Stacked:  Your problem is also similar to [Boost.Thread throws bad_alloc exception in VS2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914666/boost-thread-throws-bad-alloc-exception-in-vs2010).

Comment: @James McNellis, Thanks, I actually found that post before writing my own post. It tried all the suggestions in the 'Accepted' answer, but it doesn't solve the problem. I'm starting to suspect a bug in Boost, how unlikely that may be. Hmm... I probably need a break :)

Comment: @Stacked:  It's not a bug in Boost; I have no problems with your test code under VC9 or VC10 with Boost 1.40, 1.42, and 1.43.  It's probably a configuration or build problem.

Comment: Ugh.  Did you notice the "mt" in the .lib name?  Compare to the "md" compiler option.

Comment: @Hans Passant, I don't understand what you mean. The 'mt' matches the /Mt(d). Seems correct IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My <strike>solution</strike> workaround goes as follows:

- Install boost using the [BoostPro Installer](http://www.boostpro.com/download/). It installs Boost in the 'C:\Program Files' directory.
- Use the (included) bcp utility to create a slimmed down copy of the boost repository. See my original post for an example.
- Add the generated headers to my project folder
- Also copy any needed libs to the project folder.
- Update the Visual Studio projects include and linker paths where needed.
- Test it.
- Commit it all to SVN.
- Voila, I know have my batteries-included code repository :)

Actually, my original question remains unanswered, I still don't know why my attempts for Boost 1.43 failed. It's probably some configuration issue. However, this is a satisfying workaround.

By the way, the reason why I reverted to Boost 1.42 is simply because the BoostPro Installer does not yet support 1.43.