# boost_thread segmentation fault on application start up

Tags: c++, boost, eclipse-cdt

I am developing an image processing application with OpenCV 2.4.6.1 version on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Eclipse Indigo. I use Intel ICC compiler version 14.

I need to use Thread Library distributed within Boost. So that I have compiled Boost 1.54 with Intel compiler successfully.

To compile with following code piece, -lboost_thread switch is added to linker's flag list:

```
boost::this_thread::sleep_for(oneFrameProcessDuration -(boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - startTime));
```

After this overall application is compiled successfully. When I start application,

```
boost::exception_ptr boost::exception_detail::get_static_exception_object<boost::exception_detail::bad_alloc_>()
```

exception is thrown. Even I cannot reach first line on my main function.

What can be the problem?

Regards.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914666/boost-thread-throws-bad-alloc-exception-in-vs2010

Comment: are you sure you're linking with the correct boost library (the one that implements your headers)? What do you get when running in debugger?

Comment: @boric I have checked that thread before posting this thread.

Comment: @walter I am sure that, I link to the correct boost library. I think there is no inconsistency between headers and libraries since I link to boost_system library without any problems. Debugger says program received SIGSEG segmentation fault signal is received and exception on original post is thrown.

Comment: Try to remove code lines until the error disappears, thus creating a minimal buggy version.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem today. As this question seems to be a top hit on google and does not have an answer, here it is:

**The simple solution:**

If you only need threads, without all the additional stuff like locking and timing, you can include `#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>` instead of `#include <boost/thread.hpp>`. This way linking with `-lboost_thread` is enough, maybe `-lboost_system` is also needed, could not test it as other parts of my code need it too.

**The more complex:**

If you need more, you may need to link with more boost libraries, like `-lboost_chrono` and `-lboost_date_time`. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/thread/build.html for more details.